# Error 500 internal server error validate key magento

Tags: magento2, error, import, csv

I'm new to Magento which makes me a big newbie. I have recently set up a localhost store using XAMPP. Now I want to import 500 products with my CSV file. I've looked up the CSV file structure and I think I did good, so I don't there are any errors there (I may be wrong too).

Anyway, after I try to upload my `.csv`, nothing happens and it keeps displaying "please wait for" message. After a while, I decided to stop and ran firebug and re-ran import.

**I got this error message**

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error -
>   https://localhost/myownstore/admin2/admin/import/validate/key/
>   <---there was a random key.

I've tried setting file permission to index.php, also changed PHP memory limit value and nothing helps.

Please help me I'm desperate :(

Comment: How did you manage to make it not say "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error..."? Sorry I cannot comment without the points

Comment: How did you solve out? I have same issue

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure there is var folder having valid write permission so export process will create file in car/export folder.

Let me know if you need help.

Comment: all my folders have file permission. i somehow have managed to fix this problem, but now i have the same problem as this post: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108194/failed-to-import-csv-to-magento

Answer (score 0):

Do one  thing 
go to

> app/bootstrap.php

in that go to line number 11 (approx) you will find below code Just uncomment it.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Once you do this after that you will get an original error instead of 500 error.

after that it will be easy to trace the problem.