# Failed to import .csv to magento

Tags: magento2, import, importexport, url-key

I'm trying to import my `.csv` file to magento using magento import (system-import).

When i choose my `.csv` file and click check data, it says file is valid and it gives me option to import. So i click import. After like 10 seconds, it gives me this error.

**Following Error(s) has been occurred during importing process:**

> Only first 100 errors are displayed here. Download full report General
>   system exception happened Additional data: URL key for specified store
>   already exists.

I literally have no idea what this means. I have already tried maximizing characters to 255, changing writing permissions and leaving url_key blank, even deleting it out of `.csv`. Nothing helps.

Any help will be appreciated!

PS: also after trying to upload when i go to dashboard, it gives me `indexers are invalid` which never happened before.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have attached two csv for configurable and simple product for your demo purpose so you can take reference on how to create it. Please try to import for simple product csv and then configurable one. I had tested it and its working fine.
 **Simple Product CSV** 
sku,attribute_set_code,product_type,categories,product_websites,color,additional_attributes,name,description,short_description,weight,product_online,tax_class_name,visibility,price,qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,allow_backorders,use_config_backorders,min_cart_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_cart_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_on_stock_below,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,website_id,deferred_stock_update,use_config_deferred_stock_update,errors
400110821753,Default,simple,Default Category/Women,base,BLACK,"color=BLACK,size=L",Test Product,Test Product,Test Product,4.5,1,None,Not Visible Individually,66.67,100,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,

**Configurable Product CSV**
sku,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,product_type,categories,product_websites,name,description,short_description,weight,product_online,tax_class_name,visibility,price,special_price,special_price_from_date,special_price_to_date,url_key,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,base_image,base_image_label,small_image,small_image_label,thumbnail_image,thumbnail_image_label,swatch_image,swatch_image_label,created_at,updated_at,new_from_date,new_to_date,display_product_options_in,map_price,msrp_price,map_enabled,gift_message_available,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,page_layout,product_options_container,msrp_display_actual_price_type,country_of_manufacture,qty,out_of_stock_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,allow_backorders,use_config_backorders,min_cart_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_cart_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_on_stock_below,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,website_id,deferred_stock_update,use_config_deferred_stock_update,related_skus,crosssell_skus,upsell_skus,additional_images,additional_image_labels,hide_from_product_page,bundle_price_type,bundle_sku_type,bundle_price_view,bundle_weight_type,bundle_values,configurable_variations,configurable_variation_labels,associated_skus
GC_105-0S2,,Default,configurable,Default Category/Women,base,ConfProd Test,ConfProd Test,ConfProd Test,,1,None,"Catalog, Search",66.67,,,,ConfProd Test,,,,/c/l/classic_fit_1_2.jpg,,/c/l/classic_fit_1_2.jpg,,/c/l/classic_fit_1_2.jpg,,,,,,,,Block after Info Column,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,,,,/c/l/classic_fit_1_2.jpg,,,,,,,,"sku=400110821753,color=BLACK,size=L","color=Color,size=Size",

Comment: I get positive response, right after go to check back end there is no products, and one more when i try to export    http://i.stack.imgur.com/LO9dL.png